# Automatically Closing Outlook Windows via Script/Macro

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook

I'm hoping someone on here can point me in the right direction with some expertise.  I have a situation with a client's outlook where we need to close any open draft windows after a new message/draft is opened. Ideally after the 4th new window has opened.

[image]

Any "new message" window that opens after this we need the script to close 1st window that opened. Either killing the process, or something similar.

Recently have been looking into Outlook macros, but am unsure if they will help in this instance. (Maybe they are?). Being more familiar with Powershell, figured we could start there.

Looking to get help writing a powershell script, macro, etc to do this on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model provides all the required events, methods and properties for that. So, VBA macros is the right choice if you don't need to distribute the solution on multiple machines. Otherwise, you need to consider developing a COM add-in instead (for example, a VSTO based one should work for you). See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

You can handle the [NewInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.newinspector) event which is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code. The event occurs after the new Inspector object is created but before the inspector window appears.

You can also check the number of opened inspector windows in Outlook by using the [Inspectors.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.count) property which returns a long indicating the count of objects in the specified collection.

Finally, the [Inspector.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.close(method)) method closes the `Inspector` and optionally saves changes to the displayed Outlook item. For example, a VBA sample which closes the active inspector instance:

```
Sub CloseItem() 
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
 Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem 
 myItem.Close olSave 
End Sub
```

Comment: Never considered this as an option. It's alot to read through, but I'll test this out and come back to you. I'm hoping it gives us the option to have the VSTO run automatically as soon as Outlook is opened.

Comment: Yes, COM add-ins can be loaded automatically with the host application.